# obtain the new value of a cell in the gridview rowUpdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to obtain the new value of a cell in the gridview rowUpdating event:

this is my code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRoles" DataKeyNames="RoleId" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Vertical" CssClass="table 
    table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvRoles_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvRoles_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowEditing="gvRoles_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleId" HeaderText="RoleId" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleName" HeaderText="RoleName" ReadOnly="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Role_Description"  HeaderText="Role Description"  ReadOnly="false" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



protected void gvRoles_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{    
  GridViewRow row = gvRoles.Rows[e.RowIndex];
  TextBox txtBox= (TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0]);
  String str = txtBox.Text;

}
```

Comment: What you are getting? old one?

Comment: yess, i've just find a solution , i must to add if(!ispostback){bindata()}